# SpringIntegration - how to run 2 queries if condition met

Tags: java, spring-integration

How can we run two queries if the  selector-expression is met? 
My goal is to 
 • delete one row from one table, and
 • insert a row into another.

```
<int:recipient channel="myChannel" 
       selector-expression="(payload.getValueForVariable('thingA') = 'this_value')"
    />

<int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter
    channel="myChannel" id="myAdapter"
    data-source='myDataSource' sql-parameter-source-factory="myRequestSource"
    query="INSERT INTO realtime.table1(a_id,  b_id)   
                                     VALUES(:a_id, :b_id)">
</int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

In above, I am having an INSERT query; now I wonder how I can make *yet another* query run as well if this condition is met, such as:

```
query="DELETE FROM realtime.table2(a_id,  b_id) WHERE a_id = :a_id">
```

I have not found an answer on this on the web, and I'd ideally like to avoid having duplication of the whole block.

Comment: I think you mean *row*. Sorry, can edit from phone

Answer (score 1):

You can make your `myChannel` as publish-subscribe-channel and have one more jdbc:outbound-channel-Adapter for the mentioned DELETE:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-implementations-publishsubscribechannel

Comment: So is it impossible to make the 
   query="INSERT ... VALUES" 
run two queries in the database to look like 
   query="INSERT ... VALUES;
               DELETE ..."

I think the reasons why I am asking this is that I don't quite understand why it should be a single query and no more.